# How to change "Device" identifier displayed in System Monitor?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks, system-monitor

System Monitor displays a list of mounted "Devices" under the "File System" tab. I would like to change the identifier that is associated with a "Device" listed in System Monitor. How can this be done?

Here's a little more background: My system has two LUKS-encrypted volumes:  one on `vda2`, and the other on `vda3`. System Monitor displays `/dev/dm-0` as the identifier for the LUKS-encrypted volume on `vda2`, but displays `/dev/mapper/vda3_crypt` as the identifier for the LUKS-encrypted volume on `vda3`.

[image]

I know this seems ridiculously picky, but I'd prefer that System Monitor use *consistent nomenclature* for the two LUKS-encrypted volumes.  That is, either use `/dev/mapper/vda2_crypt` and `/dev/mapper/vda3_crypt` (for volumes on vda2 and vda3, respectively) or use `/dev/dm-0` and `/dev/dm-1` (for volumes on vda2 and vda3, respectively).  Is there a way to force this?

I'll just add that changes to neither crypttab nor fstab have any effect on what System Monitor displays. So on what does System Monitor rely for determining how to name these devices?  A config file?  If so, located where?

For anyone who is curious, here's how these volumes were created: Using the “something else” option presented during installation of 15.10, I created a LUKS-encrypted volume on vda2, and I then installed boot (/boot) into non-encrypted vda1, and root (/) into the LUKS-encrypted vda2  formatted with Ext4. I then booted into Ubuntu and created an auto-mounting LUKS-encrypted vda3 formatted with Ext4, to which I moved my home directory.

I used the above approach to overcome a bug that prevents the direct installation of /home into a separate LUKS encrypted volume during installation of Ubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu 16.04. For more information about that bug, see

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1523194

Comment: System monitor *looks* like it reads "live" (or just mounted) devices from /dev or maybe another system folder... but devices like sda & sdb have their letters switched on different boots, so I'm guessing it's difficult at the least. Why rely on system monitor anyway? Use a conky & an if to label it however you like... or change System monitor's source code & add an if there?

Comment: @Xen2050:  Thanks for the feedback.  Yep, I'm afraid that System Monitor probably creates the identifier on-the-fly, but based on what, I still can't figure out. I'll just note that I recently installed root (/) into a LUKS-encrypted volume on vda2 formatted with Btrfs instead of Ext4, and strangely, System Monitor identifies that Device as `/dev/mapper/vda2_crypt`, not as `/dev/dm-0` as it does when installing into Ext4.  So, I'm not sure what's going on.  As for why I use System Monitor, no I don't "rely" on it.  But it's a default program, and I'd like it to work properly.